# Examples of doing decimal math in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsdecimalnumber

I'm pulling decimal values from a sql table as a text field which i then convert to an NSDecimalNumber (this is simply because i didnt know read/write decimal values to sqllite).

Anyway, now i've hit a wall now that im trying to do simple math routines on these decimal variables. Such as, Sum = Balance * Interest_Rate. The idea is that im working with money calculations.

Do you know of samples/tutorials that teaches how to do these operations using either NSDecimal, NSDecimalNumber, or both?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a float to store the number? It's very easy to convert a string to a float. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/floatValue

Comment: Yes. everything ive read suggests not to use float/double for money related calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To init:

```
NSString *number = @"123.4";
NSDecimalNumber *myDecimal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString: number];
```

To do what you want to do:

```
NSDecimalNumber *sum = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:[balance decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy: interest_rate];
```

How?

Well you make a NSDecimalNumber and alloc and then initWithDecimal. What decimal? balance multiplied (decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy) by interest_rate.

Comment: But isn't there a way to perform operations using NSDecimal?